# Uncaught exception without stack trace in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe and from time to time I get uncaught exception without stack trace.

I added console.log  prints and it appears the exception happens after the test finished.
I can see the last console.log which is the last command in the test.

I double checked to see if we have afterEach function and we don't.

Any idea where can I look for the problem?

Comment: Could you please share an image of the uncaught exception?